# In Ubuntu 18.04 GUI everything is too big

Tags: gnome, graphics, 18.04

I just upgraded Ubuntu on a PC from 17.10 to 18.04 and everything on the display is too big! Here is a picture of my monitor which I took with my cell phone:

[image]

I installed Kubuntu desktop using tasksel and it is working fine, but Ubuntu's native desktop does not work well and does not scale on the monitor. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop, which did not work. I tried installing some drivers, which again, did not work.

Comment: Check settings for screen resolution and settings for scaling. Information on your configuration and graphics card may also help.

Comment: didn't work :( I ended up installing kubuntu shell